# Stripe payments APIConnection error

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am using the stripe and django/python.

However, I keep getting an intermittent APIConnection error:

```
Network error: ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.stripe.com', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/customers/cus_4vxaUg0FRgH5Ll (Caused by <class 
'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution))
```

See here for full report: http://dpaste.com/0KMVZ92

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: connection issues perhaps?

Comment: No solution.  But it could be a couple things.  Either the url isn't resolving itself or stripe api is exceeding a timeout limit.  It seems like it's an issue on stripe's end, such as being overloaded and closing the connection prematurely sometimes.  I'd try running the same tests from a different location to see if you could reproduce the error.  If not, see if it's dumping the customer with that id `4vxaUg0FRgH5Ll`.  That would cause the url to never resolve, since the customer object doesn't exist.  Unfortunately it's a rather ambiguous answer which could have multiple causes and solutions

Comment: I'm having the same issue (django/python/django-stripe-payments). Did you ever resolve this or find out what the issue was?

Comment: I was having the same problem with some sites and upgrading the Python version of Stripe seems to have taken care of this (I only upgrade a little while ago so time will tell).

Answer (score 0):

Name resolution error means you have a DNS name resolution error.